# Concatenate many Future[Seq] into one Future[Seq]

Tags: scala, future, seq, circuit-breaker

Without Future, that's how I combine all smaller Seq into one big Seq with a **flatmap**

```
category.getCategoryUrlKey(id: Int):Seq[Meta] // main method
val appDomains: Seq[Int]

val categories:Seq[Meta] = appDomains.flatMap(category.getCategoryUrlKey(_))
```

Now the method `getCategoryUrlKey` could fail. I put a circuit breaker in front to avoid to call it for the next elements after an amount of **maxFailures**. Now the circuit breaker doesn't return a `Seq` but a `Future[Seq]`

```
lazy val breaker = new akka.pattern.CircuitBreaker(...)

private def getMeta(appDomainId: Int): Future[Seq[Meta]] = {
  breaker.withCircuitBreaker {
    category.getCategoryUrlKey(appDomainId)
  }
}
```

How to iterate through the List `appDomains` and combine the result into one single Future[Seq] , possible into Seq ?

If Functional Programming is applicable, is there a way to directly transform without temporary variables ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Squash seq of futures using Future.sequence

`Future.sequence`converts `Seq[Future[T]]` to `Future[Seq[T]]`

In your case `T` is `Seq`. After the sequence operation, you will end up with Seq[Seq[T]]. So Just flatten it after the sequence operation using flatten.

```
def squashFutures[T](list: Seq[Future[Seq[T]]]): Future[Seq[T]] =
  Future.sequence(list).map(_.flatten)
```

Your code becomes

```
Future.sequence(appDomains.map(getMeta)).map(_.flatten)
```

Comment: Ok , I have to store first into Seq[Future[Seq[T]]] , then I can `squashFutures` . Is there a way to directly transform without temporary variables ?

Comment: @RaymondChenon `Future.sequence(appDomains.map(getMeta)).map(_.flatten)` is what you have to do. There are no temp variables here

Comment: You sir are a hero.

Answer (score 1):

## From TraversableOnce[Future[A]] to Future[TraversableOnce[A]]

```
val categories = Future.successful(appDomains).flatMap(seq => {
    val fs = seq.map(i => getMeta(i))
    val sequenced = Future.sequence(fs)
    sequenced.map(_.flatten)
})
```

- `Future.successful(appDomains)` lifts the `appDomains` into the context of `Future`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
val metaSeqFutureSeq = appDomains.map(i => getMeta(i))
// Seq[Future[Seq[Meta]]]

val metaSeqSeqFuture = Future.sequence(metaSeqFutureSeq)
// Future[Seq[Seq[Meta]]]
// NOTE :: this future will fail if any of the futures in the sequence fails

val metaSeqFuture = metaSeqSeqFuture.map(seq => seq.flatten)
// Future[Seq[Meta]]
```

If you want to reject the only failed futures but keep the successful one's then we will have to be a bit creative and build our future using a promise.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

def futureSeqToOptionSeqFuture[T](futureSeq: Seq[Future[T]]): Future[Seq[Option[T]]] = {
  val promise = Promise[Seq[Option[T]]]()

  var remaining = futureSeq.length

  val result = ArrayBuffer[Option[T]]()
  result ++ futureSeq.map(_ => None)

  val resultLock = new ReentrantLock()

  def handleFutureResult(option: Option[T], index: Int): Unit = {
    resultLock.lock()
    result(index) = option
    remaining = remaining - 1
    if (remaining == 0) {
      promise.success(result)
    }
    resultLock.unlock()
  }

  futureSeq.zipWithIndex.foreach({ case (future, index) => future.onComplete({
    case Success(t) => handleFutureResult(Some(t), index)
    case Failure(ex) => handleFutureResult(None, index)
  }) })

  promise.future
}

val metaSeqFutureSeq = appDomains.map(i => getMeta(i))
// Seq[Future[Seq[Meta]]]

val metaSeqOptionSeqFuture = futureSeqToOptionSeqFuture(metaSeqFutureSeq)
// Future[Seq[Option[Seq[Meta]]]]

val metaSeqFuture = metaSeqSeqFuture.map(seq => seq.flatten.flatten)
// Future[Seq[Meta]]
```