# Converting a (List of Future of Either) into a (Future of Either of List) in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, future

I have a situation in a pet Scala project that I don't really know how to overcome.

The following example shows my problem.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class MyBoard(id: Option[Int], name: String)
case class MyList(id: Option[Int], name: String, boardId: Option[Int] = None)
case class ErrorCreatingList(error: String)

def createList(myList: MyList): Future[Either[ErrorCreatingList, MyList]] =
  Future {
    // Let's close our eyes and pretend I'm calling a service to create this list
    Right(myList)
  }

def createLists(myLists: List[MyList],
                myBoard: MyBoard): Future[Either[ErrorCreatingList, List[MyList]]] = {

  val listsWithId: List[Future[scala.Either[ErrorCreatingList, MyList]]] =
    myLists.map { myList =>
      createList(myList.copy(boardId = myBoard.id))
    }

  //  Meh, return type doesn't match
  ???
}
```

I wanted `createLists` to return `Future[Either[ErrorCreatingList, List[MyList]]]` but I don't know how to do it, because `listsWithId` has the type `List[Future[scala.Either[ErrorCreatingList, MyList]]]`, which makes sense.

Is there a way to do it? A friend told me "and that's what Cats is for", but is it the only option, I mean, can't I do it using just what's in the Scala core library?

Thanks.

Comment: Suggested read: https://blog.buildo.io/monad-transformers-for-the-working-programmer-aa7e981190e7 - it presents a rather similar problem, and a rather simple solution, which has a "big name" ("Monad Transformer") but is a simple, well-explained concept that might help here too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many Future\[Seq\] into one Future\[Seq\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585910/concatenate-many-futureseq-into-one-futureseq)

Answer (score 4):

Use `Future.sequence` on your `List[Future[???]]` to make `Future[List[???]]`

```
val listOfFuture: List[Future[???]] = ???

val futureList: Future[List[???]] = Future.sequence(listOfFuture)
```

Comment: This creates future list of eithers ... not what the OP wanted.

Comment: It's actually my bad because the title of the question is misleading

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do it with Cats:

```
listFutureEither.traverse(EitherT(_)).value
```

---

Here is how one can quickly see that "there must be something like this in scala-cats already":

- `Future` is a monad
- `Future[Either[E, ?]]` is essentially `EitherT[E, Future, ?]`, therefore it's also a monad
- Every `Monad` is automatically an `Applicative`
- So, `M[X] = EitherT[E, Future, X]` is an `Applicative`
- For every applicative `A` and traversable `T`, it is trivial to swap `T[A[X]]` into `A[T[X]]`.
- `List` has a `Traverse` instance
- you should be able to use `Traverse[List]` to get from `List[EitherT[E, Future, X]]` to `EitherT[E, Future, List[X]]`
- From there, it's trivial to get to `Future[Either[E, List[X]]]`

Translating this step-by-step explanation into code yields:

```
// lines starting with `@` are ammonite imports of dependencies,
// add it to SBT if you don't use ammonite
@ import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-core:1.1.0`
@ import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.Either

// your input
val listFutureEither: List[Future[Either[String, Int]]] = Nil 

// monad transformer stack appropriate for the problem
type M[X] = EitherT[Future, String, X]

// converting input into monad-transformer-stack
val listM = listFutureEither.map(EitherT[Future, String, Int](_))

// solving your problem
val mList = Traverse[List].sequence[M, Int](listM)

// removing all traces of the monad-transformer-stack
val futureEitherList: Future[Either[String, List[Int]]] = mList.value
```

Fusing `map` + `sequence` into `traverse` and cleaning up some unnecessary type parameters results in the much shorter solution above.

Comment: The problem is that traverse, in this case, does not stop on the first left result, it will execute all the Futures.

Comment: @SergeyBelash I'm afraid that's not `Traverse`'s fault, it's because the `Future`s in general can't be created without the side-effect of immediately starting the computation of whatever they're computing. So, if you have a list with `n` `Future`s of somethings, you'll be computing `n` somethings, regardless of how you later process the resulting list. If that's not the behavior that you want, then you should replace Scala's default `Future` by some `Task`-implementation of your favorite flavor, so it doesn't start any computations before you ask it to.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the explanation. Actually, I tried it with monix.Task, and the result was the same. But I guess it was because I tried to use ".runAsync" which just converted the tasks into Futures.

Answer (score 2):

So, `val eithers = Future.traverse(myLists)(createList)`  will give you `Future[List[Either[ErrorCreatingList, MyList]]]`.

You can now transform it to what you want, but that depends on how you want to deal with the errors. What happens if some requests returned an error, and others succeeded?

This example returns `Right[List[MyList]]` if everything succeeded, and `Left` with the first error otherwise:

```
type Result = Either[ErrorCreatingList, List[MyList]]
val result: Future[Result] = eithers.map { 
   _.foldLeft[Result](Right(Nil)) { 
     case (Right(list), Right(myList)) => Right(myList :: list)
     case (x @ Left(_), _) => x
     case (_, Left(x)) => Left(x)
  }.right.map(_.reverse)
}
```

I am not `cats` expert, but I think the only thing it helps with here is not having to type `.right` before `.map` at the end ... but scala 2.12 does that by default too.

There is another library, called `scalactic`, that adds some interesting features, letting you combine multiple errors together ... but you'd have to have errors on the right for that to work ... which would be incompatible with pretty much everything else. It's not hard to combine those errors "manually" if you have to, I'd say just do that rather than switching to scalactic, which, besides being incompatible,  has a considerable learning curve and hurts readability.

Comment: Thanks @Dima. I'm going to give your answer a try. Right now, I have some compilation errors. Even after removing the `[` and `]` surrounding the `Either` (in the definition of `Result`) and changing `mylist` to `myList` I'm getting "type mismatch" errors in the 1st and 3rd `case`s. I'll try to figure them out myself and I'll give you some feedback so that, if some fixes are needed, we can fix them for future reference.

Comment: @Dima Not sure whether `.right.` is needed there. Consider running it once again through the compiler.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin right is needed in scala 2.11, but not 2.12, where `Either` is right-biased ,so, you can map it directly